# Reason for LCM of all numbers from 1 .. n equals roughly $e^n$

Tags: number-theory, exponential-function, least-common-multiple

I computed the LCM for all natural numbers from 1 up to a limit $n$ and plotted the result over $n$.  Due to the fast-raising numbers, I plotted the logarithm of the result and was surprised to find a (more or less) identity curve ($x=y$).

In other words, $LCM(1, 2, 3, ..., n)$ appears to be roughly the value $e^n$.

Is a there a simple explanation on why this is so?

$LCM(a, b, c, …)$ shall be defined as the least common multiple of all arguments $a, b, c, …$

[image: plot of $ln(LCM(1, 2, 3, …, n))$ over $n$]

Comment: Your observation is closely related to a theorem about the asymptotic behaviour of the [Second Chebyshev Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) $\psi(x)$, the logarithm of the lcm of the numbers $1$ to $x$. It turns out that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\psi(x)}{x}=1$.

Comment: Why was @Xiang Yu's comment below not even noticed, even less addressed?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834220/least-common-multiple-lim-sqrtn1-2-dotsc-n-e

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is basically a different way to state exactly what André Nicolas said in a comment, but observe that the largest power of a given prime $p$ found as a factor in a number less than $n$ is explicitly given by
$$
\lfloor\log_p(n)\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{\ln n}{\ln p}\right\rfloor
$$
so we can write $LCM(n)=LCM(1,2,...,n)$ explicitly as
$$
LCM(n)=\prod_{p\leq n}p^{\left\lfloor\frac{\ln n}{\ln p}\right\rfloor}
$$
Applying $\ln(x)$ to both sides, we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\ln(LCM(n))&=\sum_{p\leq n}\left\lfloor\frac{\ln n}{\ln p}\right\rfloor\cdot\ln p\\
&\approx \sum_{p\leq n}\frac{\ln n}{\ln p}\cdot\ln p\\
&=\ln n\cdot\sum_{p\leq n}1\\
&=\ln n\cdot \pi(n)
\end{align}
$$
where $\pi(n)$ denotes the function counting primes less than or equal to $n$. Now since by the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) we have $\pi(n)\sim\frac{n}{\ln n}$ so that these converge asymptotically, we get closer and closer to equality in the following approximation for $\ln(LCM(n))$:
$$
\begin{align}
\ln(LCM(n))&\approx\ln n\cdot\pi(n)\\
&\approx\ln n\cdot\frac{n}{\ln n}\\
&=n
\end{align}
$$
Applying the inverse of $\ln(x)$, namely $\text{e}^x$, then shows your statement. Note that the rounding off done by the floor functions becomes asymptotically insignificant.

Comment: Not as simple as I hoped for, but I managed.  And furthermore I think it won't get much simpler than that.

Comment: We need to consider the error term. Note that
\begin{align}
\log(\mathrm{lcm}\{1,\dots,n\})&=\sum_{p\leq n}\left\lfloor \frac{\log n}{\log p}\right\rfloor \log p=\sum_{p\leq n} (\frac{\log n}{\log p}+O(1))\log p\\
                               &=\sum_{p\leq n}\log n+O(\log p)=\pi(n)\log n+O(\sum_{p\leq n}\log n)\\
                               &=\pi(n)\log n+O(\theta (n)),
\end{align} where $\theta$ is the first Chebyshev function. Since $\theta(x)\sim x$, the error term is the same size as the main term!

Comment: "Note that the rounding off done by the floor functions becomes asymptotically insignificant." A missing part, if true.