# Proof of the limit using only elementary techniques

Tags: limits

Today I saw this limit and I was baffled by  it.

$$e=\lim_{ n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,4,\ldots,n)}$$

Is there an elementary proof of the result?

Comment: First time I see this one, and it looks very interesting. I would doubt that there's any elementary proof of that. Perhaps you should start with asking what $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n!}$ is equal to... BTW, it's not specified **even** on the [definition of $e$ in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) (which lists quite a few alternative ways for calculating it). So if this is indeed true, then perhaps you want to add it there.

Comment: Does this imply $\text{lcm}(1,2,\ldots,n)\to e^n$ as $n\to\infty$ ?

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111334/reason-for-lcm-of-all-numbers-from-1-n-equals-roughly-en

Comment: @pbs: No. $e^n$ is a moving target, so nothing can tend to it. If you want to ask whether lcm$(1,2,...,n) - e^n$ tends to $0$, then the answer is still no. The ratio tends to $1$ (if the OP is to be believed), but that doesn't mean that the difference must tend to $0$, because both expressions grow without limit.

Comment: @TonyK: According to the related question (linked one comment above yours), it actually does imply it (though it probably needs to be phrased with a different notation).

Comment: @barak: I think you must be mistaken. For instance, $e^n$ is not, in general, especially close to an integer, whereas lcm$(...)$ is. Perhaps you didn't notice that $n$th roots are not being taken.

Comment: @TonyK: I don't know, that's what the graph in that other question shows...

Comment: @barak: Read my edited comment.

Comment: @TonyK ok yes not a limit ("tends to") - my mistake. But maybe it is approximately $e^n$.