# least common multiple of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ is bigger than $2^{n-1}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, gcd-and-lcm

> The least common multiple of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ is greater than $2^{n-1}$ for any $n \ge 3$.

I found this in a MATHEMATICA book, but I don't know how to prove this. Can you help me?

[Edit: [This thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/834220/11619) has a discussion of an asymptotic stronger result, but that relies on the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem). What else is known about this? JL]

Comment: I'd like to see a proof of this based on the fact that $lcm(1,2,\dots,n)$ is the maximum order of an element in the symmetric group $S_n$.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{LCM(1,2,\ldots,n)}=e$

Comment: @Lucian please tell what is your limit conveying regarding this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GA316: It shows that $LCM_n\simeq C~e^n>2^n>2^{n-1}$ for large enough values of *n*.

Comment: @Lucian ya. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ihf When you say maximum, it suggests it could be achieved... The fact that it cannot be achieved might make it very tricky...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.2295v2.pdf) proves the identity
$$
\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,\dots,n)=n \operatorname{lcm}\left(\binom{n-1}{0}, \binom{n-1}{1},\dots,\binom{n-1}{n-1}\right)
$$
by computing the number of factors of $p$ which appear in each expression, for all primes $p$.

From this it follows that
$$
\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,\dots,n) \geq n \binom{n-1}{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor} \geq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k}=2^{n-1}
$$

Comment: Beautiful, +1. There are some comments to this effect on [oeis](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+6%2C+12%2C+60%2C+60%2C+420&language=english&go=Search).

Answer (score 26):

Here is a neat proof:

Consider the product
$$\text{lcm}(1, 2, \dots, 2n + 1)\int_0^1 (x)^n(1 - x)^n \text{d}x$$
This is an integer, because expanding using the binomial theorem and integrating each part gives an integer.  Additionally, the integral is less than
$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac14\right)^n \text{d}x = \frac{1}{4^n}$$
so
$$\text{lcm}(1, 2, \dots, 2n + 1) > 4^n = 2^{2n}$$
which proves the desired inequality for odd values.

To prove it for even values, consider the product
$$\text{lcm}(1, 2, \dots, 2n)\int_0^1 (x)^{n}(1-x)^{n-1} \text{d}x$$
This product is also an integer.  Additionally, the integral is less than
$$\int_0^1 x\left(\frac14\right)^{n-1}\text{d}x = \frac{1}{2\cdot4^{n-1}}$$
so we arrive at
$$\text{lcm}(1, 2, \dots, 2n) > 2\cdot4^{n-1} = 2^{2n - 1}$$
which proves the desired result for even values.

Comment: Amazing solution! what was your intuition behind this trick?

Comment: I don't know.  This problem was on a math contest I participated in (Intermountain Math Competition 2019).  The first part of the problem was to show that $\text{lcm}(1, 2, \dots, 2n + 1)\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^n\text{d}x$ is an integer, and the second was to prove that $\text{lcm}(1, 2, \dots, 2n + 1) > 4^n$.

Comment: I found that this is due to M. Nair, 1982, On  Chebyshev-type  inequalities  for  primes, https://www.jstor.org/stable/2320934.

Answer (score 2):

*(Updated due to **lhf**'s comment)*.

In a few words,

$$
LCM(1,2,...,n) = e^{\psi(n)},
$$
where $\psi(n)$ is second [Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) (see formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function#Relationships)).

In fact, it is enough to prove that
$$
\psi(n) > (n-1)\ln 2 \approx 0.693(n-1).\tag{1}
$$

Function $\psi(n)$ has asymptotic $\psi(n) \sim n$.
Using lower bound for $\psi(n)$
$$
\psi(n)>0.916n−2.318\tag{2}
$$
(see discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128470/what-are-the-best-known-lower-and-upper-bounds-for-the-second-chebyshev-function) and paper [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195570997), Lemma $2$, p.$179$)
we get $(1)$ immediately for $n\ge 8$.

And it remains to check $(1)$ manually for $n=1,2,...,7$.
It is shown in this table:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & \psi(n) & (n-1)\ln 2 \\ \hline
2 & 1.79176 & 0.693147 \\
3 & 2.48491 & 1.38629 \\
4 & 4.09434 & 2.07944 \\
5 & 4.09434 & 2.77259 \\
6 & 6.04025 & 3.46574 \\
7 & 6.73340 & 4.15888 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Nagura's paper gives $\psi(x) > 0.916x - 2.318$, which settles the claim for $n\ge 8$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$.
$\bullet$ If $n=2k+1$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
We set  $I_n=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}}{k+j+1}$.  $k+1,...,2k+1$ are divisors of  $\text{lcm}\left( 1,...,n \right)$, so $\text{lcm}\left( 1,...,n \right)I_n \in \mathbb{Z}$. We have $$I_n=\sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^j\binom{n}{k}\int_{0}^{1}t^{k+j}dt=\int_{0}^{1}t^k(1-t)^kdt$$
On the othere hand,   $I_n>0$, hence $\text{lcm}\left( 1,...,n \right)I_n  \ge 1$. Moreover $\sup_{0\le t\le1}t^k(1-t)^k=\frac{1}{2^{2k}}$ so $\text{lcm}\left( 1,...,n \right)\ge \frac{1}{I_n}\ge 2^{2k}=2^{n-1}$.
$\bullet$ If $n=2k$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$.
We set $J_n=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}}{k+j}$.  $k,...,2k$ are divisors of  $\text{lcm}\left( 1,...,n \right)$, so $\text{lcm}\left( 1,...,n \right)J_n \in \mathbb{Z}$. We have  $$J_n=\sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}\int_{0}^{1}t^{k-1+j}dt=\int_{0}^{1}t^{k-1}(1-t)^kdt$$
On the othere hand ,   $J_n>0$, hence $\text{lcm}\left( 1,...,n \right)J_n  \ge 1$. Moreover $\sup_{0\le t\le1}t^{k-1}(1-t)^k=\left( \frac{k-1}{2k-1} \right)^{k-1}\left( \frac{k-2}{2k-1} \right)^{k}\le \frac{1}{2^{2k-1}}$ so $\text{lcm}\left( 1,...,n \right)\ge \frac{1}{J_n}\ge 2^{2k-1}=2^{n-1}$.

Comment: This doesn’t seem very different from the answer by Joseph Camacho.