# Do Arithmetic Mean and Geometric Mean of Prime Numbers converge?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was looking at a list of primes. I noticed that $ \frac{AM (p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n)}{p_n}$ seemed to converge.

This led me to try $ \frac{GM (p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n)}{p_n}$ which also seemed to converge.

I did a quick Excel graph and regression and found the former seemed to converge to $\frac{1}{2}$ and latter to $\frac{1}{e}$. As with anything related to primes, no easy reasoning seemed to point to those results (however, for all natural numbers it was trivial to show that the former asymptotically tended to $\frac{1}{2}$).

Are these observations correct and are there any proofs towards:

$$
{
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{AM (p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n)}{p_n} \right)
= \frac{1}{2} \tag1 
}
$$

$$
{
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{GM (p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n)}{p_n} \right)
= \frac{1}{e} \tag2
}
$$

Also, does the limit $$
{
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{HM (p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n)}{p_n} \right) \tag3
}
$$ exist?

Comment: Can we take $p_n = n\cdot log(n)$ in these limits? (using the prime numbers theorem)

Comment: What are AM, GM & HM?

Comment: @corey979 Arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic means; together, these are known as the [Pythagorean means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_means).

Comment: For what it's worth, the answer to the question in the title is "No".

Comment: @Soham Do not edit your question to ask more questions. It invalidates existing answers. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: We also [have](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834220) $$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[\large^n]{\text{LCM}[1,2,3,\ldots,n]},$$ where LCM stands for [least common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple).

Comment: I think it's really ironic that the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ are also valid for every sequence of $n$ consecutive positive integer numbers.

Comment: @polfosol It's not ironic at all. Primes cannot be pinned down to precision but are nevertheless, in a way, homogeneously distributed among numbers. i.e. we know that numbers divisible by 2 occur every 2nd place, by 3 every 3rd place, by 5 every 5th place and so on..So, multiples of 2 will follow eqn 1 and 2, so will multiples of 3, of 5, of 7....so also, will numbers that aren't multiples of 2, or of 3, or of 5 etc....so, why shouldn't numbers that are multiples of neither 2 nor 3 nor 5 nor 7 etc follow these eqn..I hope you get what I mean, I'm writing this very roughly

Comment: @Soham I get that. But still... ironic-ness is a matter of taste ;)

Comment: Upon further observation, I notice that if we instead take nth power of primes, the limit in the equation 1 tends to $\frac{1}{n+1}$, the limit in equation 2 tends to $\frac{1}{e^n}$, and the limit in equation 3 always tends to zero. Also, I'm wondering how often do difference of eqns 1, 2, 3 change sign as n is varied from k to k+1. i.e. we take any of the eqns, say eqn 1, find its value for n=1, for 2, for 3 and so on till infinity, and then find diff between the value at n=2 and n=1, between n=3 and n=2 and so on, and then see what proportion of these differences are negative.

Answer (score 105):

Your conjecture for GM was proved in 2011 in the short paper *[On a limit involving the product of prime numbers](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-17/NNTDM-17-2-01-03.pdf)* by József Sándor and Antoine Verroken.

> **Abstract**. Let $p_k$ denote the $k$th prime number. The aim of this note is to prove that the limit of the sequence $(p_n / \sqrt[n]{p_1 \cdots p_n})$ is $e$.

The authors obtain the result based on the prime number theorem, i.e.,
$$p_n \approx n \log n \quad \textrm{as} \ n \to \infty$$
as well as an inequality with Chebyshev's function $$\theta(x) = \sum_{p \le x}\log p$$
where $p$ are primes less than $x$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I think we simply can't conclude that the sequence is strictly decreasing based on the first $15$ values. In a [paper from 2016](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.00855.pdf) on the same topic, the author points out that the sequence converges slowly.

Comment: Thanks. Does the similar limit for HM also converge to a non-zero value?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Also, going to a third digit clarifies the issue: the $GM/p_n$ for $n=5$ is about $0.428$ and the $GM/p_n$ for $n=6$ is about $0.429$, so even in the beginning the sequence is not strictly decreasing.

Comment: @Soham Good question. For positive $x_i$, we have $\min(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \le HM(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \le n\min(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. This means that for the first $n$ primes,
$$2 \le HM(p_1,\ldots,p_n) \le 4,$$
so the limit of $HM/p_n$ will vanish to $0$.

Comment: @Théophile Do you mean $2 \leq HM(p_1, \ldots, p_m) \leq 2n$?  The result still follows, of course, since $\frac{2n}{n\log n} \to 0$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire : the formula in the cited literature is just your reciprocal. Additionally, if you use $p_{n-1}$ in the denominator of your formula it looks as if this could as well converge to $e$...

Comment: @Soham: sorry, my previous comment should go to you instead of TheSimpliFire

Comment: @mathmandan Oh, yes, I meant $2n$, not $4$.

Comment: The abstract starts with "Let $p_k$ denote the *k*th prime number" but then uses $p_n$ and *n* everywhere else. Is that a mistake in the paper or is that some convention I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Moyli That's not strange. They defined the function $p_k$ with parameter $k$ and then they "call" it using $n$ as parameter. They probably wanted to avoid "binding" $n$ that is used later on.

Answer (score 63):

We can use the simple version of the prime counting function
$$p_n \approx n \log n$$ and plug it into your expressions.  For the arithmetic one, this becomes $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\sum_{i=1}^n p_i}{np_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\sum_{i=1}^n i\log(i)}{np_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\sum_{i=1}^n \log(i^i)}{np_n}\\=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\log\prod_{i=1}^n i^i}{np_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac {\log(H(n))}{n^2\log(n)}$$
Where $H(n)$ is the [hyperfactorial function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html).  We can use the expansion given on the Mathworld page to get 
$$\log H(n)\approx \log A -\frac {n^2}4+\left(\frac {n(n+1)}2+\frac 1{12}\right)\log (n)$$
and the limit is duly $\frac 12$

I didn't find a nice expression for the product of the primes.

Comment: Thanks. Not as though I understand the proof, though..haha

Comment: So, I just tried the same with HM too..This one I'm not sure, converged or not, to a non-zero number..could well be going to zero..For the first 1 lakh numbers, it dropped down to 0.02 levels..Does this limit exist?

Comment: I added some detail of how I got to $H(n)$.  The asymptotic expansion came from the Mathworld page I linked to.

Comment: In which sense are you using the $\approx$ symbol? It's not clear to me that you can simply replace $p_i$ with $i \log i$ in your computations. In general this kind of replacement properties do not hold.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: It is valid with the standard definition, $p_n \approx n \log(n) \iff p_n = n \log(n) + o(p_n)$. If you plug this exact value into $\frac{\sum p_i}{np_n}$ you get $\frac{\sum i\log(i)}{np_n} + \frac{o(p_n)}{np_n}$. The rightmost part vanishes to $0$ near infinity so everything is fine.

Answer (score 49):

Here is a general answer to this which will solve the case for AM, GM and HM in one shot.

Observe that since $p_n \sim n\log n$, as $n \to \infty$ the proportion of numbers formed by the sequence of ratios $\frac{p_1}{p_n},\frac{p_2}{p_n} \ldots, \frac{p_{n-1}}{p_n}$ which fall inside any sub-interval within $(0,1)$ is proportion to the length of that interval i.e. the sequence $\frac{p_r}{p_n}$ approaches [equidistributed in $(0,1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence)  [*for the proof of equi/uniform distribution, see the comment below by Mariuslp*]. Hence, for an equidistributes sequence, we have:

> **Theorem**: Let $p_k$ be the $k$-th prime and let $f$ be a continuous function Riemann
>   integrable in $(0,1)$ then,
>
> $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r = 1}^{n}f\Big(\frac{p_r}{p_n}\Big) = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx. $$

([See the proof in this MO link for a direct proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311085/riemann-sum-formula-for-definite-integral-using-prime-numbers)). Taking $f(x) = x, \log(x)$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ respectively with some manipulations, we get the required limit for AM, GM and HM as $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{e}$ and $0$ respectively.

**Example**: Showing the case for GM due to request in the bellow comments. Let 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(p_1 p_2 \ldots p_n)^{1/n}}{p_n} 
= \lim_{n \to \infty}\Big(\frac{p_1}{p_n}\Big)^{1/n} \Big(\frac{p_2}{p_n}\Big)^{1/n} \ldots \Big(\frac{p_n}{p_n}\Big)^{1/n} = l
$$

Clearly, $0 < l < 1$. Taking logarithm on both sides, we have
$$
\log l = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r = 1}^{n}\log \Big(\frac{p_r}{p_n}\Big) = \int_{0}^{1} \log x dx = -1.
$$

Hence $l = 1/e$.

Comment: In which sense are those ratios uniformly distributed? What is the probability space here? And isn't the last of those ratios always 1?

Comment: I don't see how that integral would be 1/e resp. 0 in the last two cases.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: For the second case, the left hand side is the logarithm of the GM, so the right hand side needs to be $-1$, not $1/e$. Also, in the third case you've got 1/HM on the left.

Comment: @celtschk, Nilotpal: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I don't get why you speak of "equidistribution modulo 1", when the numbers are below 1. Shouldn't that be simply "equidistributed on $[0,1]$" ?

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha: As counterintuitive as it is to me you are right. For those who struggled like me, in $[\alpha, \beta]$ there are $\pi(\beta p_n) - \pi(\alpha p_n) \approx \frac{\beta p_n}{\ln (\beta p_n)} - \frac{\alpha p_n}{\ln (\alpha p_n)}$ primes, on a total of $\pi(p_n) \approx \frac{p_n}{\ln(p_n)}$. Knowing that $\ln(an) \approx \ln(n)$ for any $a>0$, with some manipulations (remember we cannot replace by equivalents in a sum), we do get a $\beta - \alpha$ proportion of primes in the interval.

Comment: The [See the proof in this MO link] broke.

Comment: @Hans: Check now I have re-linked it. Also you can use this link directly: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311085/riemann-sum-formula-for-definite-integral-using-prime-numbers

Comment: Thank you, Nilotpal.

Answer (score 22):

Not an answer, but an illustration of the type of convergence of (2). I reproduced the formula for the geometrical mean in the version reciprocal to the OP's formula to match the formula of the cited literature. The curve shows the deviation from $e$ and the slowness of convergence.

[image: picture]

The red curve is the running mean using 7 data points.

Answer (score 17):

About the harmonic mean: I believe that it exists, but it is zero.

The harmonic mean limit (HML) is
$$HML=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{HM(p_1,p_2,\ldots)}{p_n}\right).$$
The harmonic mean itself can be written as
$$HM(p_1,p_2,\ldots)=\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{p_i}}.$$
The asymptotic behavior of the sum in the fraction is (see [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicSeriesofPrimes.html)):
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{p_i}=\ln \ln p_n + B_1 + o(1),$$
with $B_1 \approx0.261$ the Mertens constant, so the asymptotic behavior of the harmonic mean is
$$HM(p_1,p_2,\ldots)=O\left(\frac{n}{\ln \ln p_n}\right)=o(n).$$

Here, $o(n)$ is the small oh-notation, which means that asymptotically, the left hand term is smaller than $n$.

Using the approximation $p_n\approx n\ln n$,
$$HML=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{o(n)}{n\ln n}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}o\left(\frac{1}{\ln n}\right)=0.$$

Comment: Personally I wouldn't bother with the last three "simplifications" before saying the limit is zero.  The first expression is "obviously" $1/g(n)$ where $g(n)$ tends (slowly) to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity

Comment: @MartinBonner: You're right, and I think a few more steps can be removed...

Answer (score 15):

This is a lower-tech alternative to Ross Millikan's answer for the Arithmetic Mean result (not using the hyperactive factorial function...), followed by a proof for the Geometric Mean (which occurred to me later).

Using $p_n\approx n\log n$ for large $n$, we need to prove

$${1\over n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n{k\log k\over\log n}\to{1\over2}$$

But for any $0\lt r\lt1$ we have

$$(1-r)\sum_{k=\lceil n^{1-r}\rceil}^nk\le\sum_{k=1}^n{k\log k\over\log n}\le\sum_{k=1}^nk={n(n+1)\over2}$$

(Note, the lower limit on the lower bounding sum is $k=\lceil n^{1-r}\rceil$; for some reason it doesn't render well in the displayed version on my screen.) Now

$$\sum_{k=\lceil n^{1-r}\rceil}^nk={n(n+1)-(\lceil n^{1-r}\rceil-1)\lceil n^{1-r}\rceil\over2}\ge{n(n+1)-n^{1-r}(n^{1-r}+1)\over2}\ge{n^2\over2}\left(1-{1\over n^{2r}}-{1\over n^{1+r}} \right)\ge{n^2\over2}\left(1-{2\over n^{2r}} \right)$$

It follows that

$${1-r\over2}\left(1-{2\over n^{2r}}\right)\le{1\over n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n{k\log k\over\log n}\le{1\over2}\left(1+{1\over n}\right)$$

Finally, let's let $r=1/\sqrt{\log n}$ Then $n^{2r}=e^{2r\log n}=e^{2\sqrt{\log n}}\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. It follows that

$${1-r\over2}\left(1-{2\over n^{2r}}\right)={1-(1/\log n)\over2}\left(1-{2\over e^{2\sqrt{\log n}}}\right)\to{1\over2}$$

and the Squeeze Theorem does the rest.

**Added later**: The low-tech approach also handles the Geometric Mean. Since $p_n/(n\log n)\to1$ as $n\to\infty$, it suffices to show

$${1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(n\log n\over p_k\right)\to1$$

If we write $p_k=(1+\epsilon_k)k\log k$ (for $k\gt1$) and note that $\epsilon_k\to0$ as $k\to\infty$, and again let $r=1/\sqrt{\log n}$ (with $n\gt2$), we have

$${1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(n\log n\over p_k\right)={1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n^{1-r}\rfloor}\log\left(n\log n\over p_k\right)+{1\over n}\sum_{k=\lceil n^{1-r}\rceil}^n\log\left(n\log n\over (1+\epsilon_k)k\log k\right)\\
={1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n^{1-r}\rfloor}\log\left(n\log n\over p_k\right)
-{1\over n}\sum_{k=\lceil n^{1-r}\rceil}^n\log(1+\epsilon_k)
+{1\over n}\sum_{k=\lceil n^{1-r}\rceil}^n\log\left(\log n\over\log k\right)
-{1\over n}\sum_{k=\lceil n^{1-r}\rceil}^n\log\left(k\over n\right)$$

Now for large $n=e^{u^2}$ (so that $r=1/u$), we have

$$0\lt{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n^{1-r}\rfloor}\log\left(n\log n\over p_k\right)\lt{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n^{1-r}\rfloor}\log\left(n\log n\over 2\right)\lt{\log(n\log n/2)\over n^r}={u^2+2\log u-\log2\over e^u}\to0$$

and

$$0\lt{1\over n}\sum_{k=\lceil n^{1-r}\rceil}^n\log\left(\log n\over\log k\right)\lt{1\over n}\sum_{k=\lceil n^{1-r}\rceil}^n\log\left(\log n\over\log n^{1-r}\right)\lt\log(1-r)\to0$$

We also have

$$\left|{1\over n}\sum_{k=\lceil n^{1-r}\rceil}^n\log(1+\epsilon_k)\right|\le\max_{\lceil n^{1-r}\rceil\le k\le n}|\log(1+\epsilon_k)|\to0$$

since the range over which the max is taken forces $\epsilon_k\to0$. Finally, we have

$$-{1\over n}\sum_{k=\lceil n^{1-r}\rceil}^n\log\left(k\over n\right)
=
{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n^{1-r}\rfloor}\log\left(k\over n\right)
-{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(k\over n\right)$$

where

$$0\lt{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n^{1-r}\rfloor}\log\left(n\over k\right)\lt{\log n\over n^r}={u^2\over e^u}\to0$$

and

$$-{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(k\over n\right)\to-\int_0^1\log x\,dx=1$$